# unable to boot directly to desktop environment

Tags: linux, users, useradd, usermod

I tried to change a user's login name with `usermod --login krypton maddy`but now everytime I reboot my pc, it doesn't directly shows the desktop environment and I need to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then `startx` and when I run `who` I get previous username at the top:

```
krypton@Elementalx:~/Desktop$ usermod --login krypton impulse
usermod: user 'impulse' does not exist
krypton@Elementalx:~/Desktop/Black Hole$ who
impulse                 2019-08-11 22:50
krypton  tty2         2019-08-11 22:52
krypton  pts/0        2019-08-11 22:53 (:1)
krypton  pts/1        2019-08-11 22:56 (:1)
```

how do I fix it.